# New Column/Row Data for CSV

Tags: vb.net, csv

I have a CSV file where I need to add new columns namely `app_modulname`, `app_module.status`, `app_module.increment`, `app_module.success`. This could easily be done with this lines of codes below.

```
Dim csvData = File.ReadLines(filename).Select(Function(line, index) 
  If(index = 0, 
    line + ",app_module.name,app_module.status,app_module.increment,app_module.success",
    line + "," + moduleName & ",inactive," & index & ",")
  )

File.WriteAllLines(savePath, csvData)
```

For the `app_module.increment` column, the row data are just increment numbers. The problem is that the code above is reading the line breaks. And, I use index as the increment number. is there other way to get the index of row?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to add the line number into each record? I'm not sure what you mean when you say that reading lines breaks is a problem. Perhaps you should provide examples of the data before and after.

Comment: What I want  is to put the row index number to the new column app_module.increment.

However, if there is a line break, it won't be in the increment column.

Comment: There are no actual columns in a CSV file. There are just lines containing commas. If you want to add "columns" then all you're doing is appending text containing commas to each line. The line breaks don't change. In your case, call `File.ReadAllLines` to create a `String` array where each element is a line from the file. You can then use a `For` loop to iterate over that array. Inside the loop, append the appropriate text to the current line. The loop counter gives you the line number.  When you're done, call `File.WriteAllLines` to write the new data out to the file.

Comment: The first cell has line break in it. 3 lines. Instead of giving 1 in my increment column first cell, it is giving 3.

The number of rows is 30. However, if there are line breaks in each cell, the ReadAllLines count is the number of rows and the number of line breaks. Thus, I am not getting the increment number that I need.

Img for reference [link](https://imgur.com/8gTmBmy)

Comment: So you're saying, without actually saying, that the data itself actually contains line breaks? If that is the case then do those field values have double quotes around them, as they should?

Comment: Some have double quotes. Some don't. Most don't have double quotes. I can see double quotes on my `address` data. Not sure how to do it with the `CSVHelper` library.

Comment: Do the fields that contain line breaks have double quotes around them? If not then it's not actually a CSV file because it doesn't follow the rules. You would need to write custom code in that case. I still don't see any data examples, which I asked for two days ago.

Comment: Line breaks have double quotes on them. However, they are in different lines. I am using ReadAllLines, like what you have said. I gave a link where you can see the data. The only thing I need to accomplish is to add one column and the data per row is the Row Index of that row.

Comment: When I suggested `File.ReadAllLines` I was unaware of the line breaks within the data. My mistake. As long as those field values that contain line breaks are wrapped in double quotes, which you say they are, then a `TextFieldParser` should handle them without issue.  I'll throw together an example and post it in an answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @jmcilhinney! Looking forward to it..

Answer (score 0):

I started with the following text file:

```
One,"First record",Primary
Two,"Second
record",Secondary
Three,"Third record",Tertiary
```

I executed this code:

```
Dim lines As New List(Of String)
Dim lineNumber = 1

Using parser As New TextFieldParser("TextFile1.txt") With {.Delimiters = {","}}
    Do Until parser.EndOfData
        Dim fields = parser.ReadFields()

        'Add quotes around the column that may be multiline.
        fields(1) = $"""{fields(1)}"""

        lines.Add(String.Join(",", fields) & "," & lineNumber)
        lineNumber += 1
    Loop
End Using

File.WriteAllLines("TextFile1.txt", lines)
```

I ended up with this text file:

```
One,"First record",Primary,1
Two,"Second
record",Secondary,2
Three,"Third record",Tertiary,3
```

Comment: Sorry this took so long. I had completely forgotten about it.